# Show correct "most visited" date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have some problems to show the most visited date. Here's how it looks like in the database:

```
date_firstvisit
2012-11-25 15:49:16
2012-11-21 17:42:40
2012-11-21 15:36:04
2012-11-20 07:39:11
2012-11-19 09:19:36
2012-11-15 23:03:24
2012-11-15 22:57:47
2012-11-15 03:10:20
2012-11-15 03:10:14
```

This SQL query should print `2012-11-15` but it only print `0000-00-00`:

```
SELECT date_firstvisit FROM visitors
GROUP BY DATE(date_firstvisit)
ORDER BY COUNT(date_firstvisit) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If I replace `SELECT date_firstvisit FROM visitors` to `SELECT * FROM visitors` it prints `2012-11-28`. This is of course wrong!

I don't know what's wrong with my SQL query so I'm asking you now, have I missed something?

**EDIT**

This code shows how I prints the data to my website. According to njk this SQL is correct but it's just keep printing `0000-00-00`.

```
$get_mostactive_date = $sql->query("SELECT DATE(date_firstvisit), COUNT(date_firstvisit) FROM visitors GROUP BY DATE(date_firstvisit) ORDER BY COUNT(date_firstvisit) DESC LIMIT 1");
$mostactive_date = $get_mostactive_date->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $mostactive_date['date_lastactive'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: beware of duplicate dates :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will show dates having the same highest number of total visits

```
SELECT DATE(date_firstvisit) Dates, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM visitors
GROUP BY DATE(date_firstvisit)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(
  SELECT MAX(s)
  FROM(
  SELECT COUNT(*) s
  FROM visitors
  GROUP BY DATE(date_firstvisit))s
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb906/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicates*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78188/1)

Comment: this is perfect and dont know how OP accepted the below answer. +1 for your solution.

Comment: @AnandPhadke I accepted njk's answer because I don't see the good thing about Kuya's SQL :) I only see more lines... sort of. Please explain why this SQL is better than the below answer. **EDIT** I see the difference now. Sweet! :D Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `DATE` function around `date_firstvisit` in your `SELECT`. You also need an alias to handle the use of functions with `PDO`.

Assuming MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE(date_firstvisit) AS firstvisit, COUNT(date_firstvisit) AS count
FROM visitors
GROUP BY DATE(date_firstvisit)
ORDER BY COUNT(date_firstvisit) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47a2f/4)

Comment: It's a pity that mysql even lets the original, invalid version execute.

Comment: @hobbs It hit me real hard when I moved from MySQL to MSSQL.

Comment: this is also good but does not totally meet the requirement. there may have possibilities that multiple dates tie up. plug in your query here and see if it still works, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78188/1 `:D`

Comment: @KuyaJohn (John Woo?) Valid point! We would need to more know about how the data is presented.

Comment: @njk Many thanks but that's just weird! It keeps showing `0000-00-00`. Please see my edit in my question to see how I prints the data.

Comment: honestly this was my first thought (*using ORDER BY and LIMIT*) :D

Comment: @ErikEdgren Try using an alias such as `...DATE(date_firstvisit) AS myDate` and one to the `COUNT`